# Directly accessing Google Drive Photos to insert URL into <img src..>

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

Now that Google is deprecating hosting Drive files with the interface
*googledrive.com/host/[doc id]* as of Aug. 31, 2016, how can I access Drive photos directly while still keeping my HtmlService code. The code I am currently using is:`<img src="'+obj.imageUrl+'" height="'+pheight+'" width="100%">`

Where *obj.imageUrl* is using a url based upon the deprecated *googledrive.com/host/[doc id]*?

Answer (score 1):

For small scale projects it's possible to the url `https://drive.google.com/uc?id=XXX` where `XXX` is the file id on Google Drive. This can be hard coded or found using `DriveApp` e.g. `DriveApp.getFilesByName(IMG_FILE).next().getId();`

Googler, Eric Koldea, has however [warned that this technique doesn't scale (see comments thread)](https://plus.google.com/+BruceMcpherson/posts/3SrcPTptk17):

> I'd caution against using this for anything popular, since I believe the quotas for serving content this way aren't very high. You may be able to use this as a hack for small projects, but you're better off going with a real solution like Google Cloud Storage or Firebase Hosting.

Comment: Thank You - mhawksey, quite helpful! I may be able to get my test code to work again with this.

Answer (score 0):

From Apps Updates - [Deprecating web hosting support in Google Drive](http://googleappsupdates.blogspot.com/2015/08/deprecating-web-hosting-support-in.html), the best option that was given is to find a new website host with Google Domains. As stated in the blog:

> For those who have used Drive to host websites, [Google Domains](https://domains.google.com/about/) can refer you to third parties for website hosting functionality. For those who use this feature to serve non-user content to web and mobile applications, [Google Cloud Platform](https://cloud.google.com/storage/) offers a solution for this purpose.

Comment: Appreciate the attempted feedback, I already read the message from the Google product manager...this is not a specific answer. My current code-base is using web apps in HtmlService with Google Apps Script. I would like to keep that code-base and development platform working without having to migrate the code to an entirely new environment.  So, I need an alternate way to pump drive files into <img src using HtmlService and Web Apps.